# How do you effectively use “non mais” to emphasize?

Tags: interjections

I understand that there are set phrases it can be used in (as mentioned in my first question about “non mais”) but what cases would it be used most naturally?

*« Non mais sérieux, c’est quoi ça ? »*

*« Non mais il est fou ! »*

*« Non mais pourquoi ? »*

Are these natural? If not, what are some good ways to use it to emphasize what you’re saying and what do they mean? Is there an equivalent in English?

Comment: English shouldn't be the topic here. You can ask for an explanation about its purpose and the circumstances in which it's used, but the question should not be focused on finding an English equivalent. I'm closing this until it's rephrased.

Comment: thank you, i changed the question!

Answer (score 2):

"Non mais" should obviously not be translated literally. It replaces a WTH (or WTF, or "Wait!"...) in the sense of "why on Earth would that happen/be?".

It could be replaced with "Attends !..." (literal translation of "Wait!"), or "sans déconner" (literal translation of "No kidding!") like in:

> Attends/Non mais/Sans déconner ! Tu es en train de me dire que...